# cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, compareto

So I need to do dynamic ordered list.

```
    public class DynArrayListOrd<T extends Comparable<T>>  {
        private T[] tab ;

        public DynArrayListOrd()
        {
          tab = (T[])new Object[startSize];
        }
        ....

        main {
          DynArrayListOrd tab = new DynArrayListOrd();

          tab.add("John");
          tab.add("Steve");
        }
```

And when I run the code I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
    at structures.DynArrayListOrd.<init>(DynArrayListOrd.java:14)
    at structures.DynamicArrayAppp.main(DynArrayListOrd.java:119)
```

Comment: You should have seen warnings when compiling!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: casting doesn't actually transform any `Object`. So `(T[]) new Object[...];` doesn't produce a `T[]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The erased type of the `T[] tab` will be `Comparable[]`. Thus, you need to use this type in the constructor:

```
public DynArrayListOrd()
{
    tab = (T[]) new Comparable[startSize];
}
```

You should also enable `unchecked` warnings to avoid these kinds of problems in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting the generic parameter, `<String>`:

`DynArrayListOrd<String> tab = new DynArrayListOrd<>();`

Your code must be:

```
public class DynArrayListOrd<T extends Comparable<T>>  {
    private List<T> tab ;

public DynArrayListOrd()
{
    tab = new ArrayList<T>();
}
....

public static void main(String[] args){
    DynArrayListOrd<String> tab = new DynArrayListOrd<>();

    tab.tab.add("John");
    tab.tab.add("Steve");
}
```

Comment: that code will produce just the same error as the above code. the error is thrown in the constructor. `(T[]) new Object[startSize];` won't magically turn an `Object[]` into a `T[]`. Please remove the answer or  correct it.

Comment: Yes, still the same :/

Comment: @szufi search for sth like "generic array creation". I've already marked the question duplicate, just have a look at the post I've selected as dup.

Comment: How did an answer that is **that** fundamentally wrong even get a single upvote?